# Android AAR file protect from reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection, aar, securitymanager

I have big problem with AAR files. I want make an AAR file and give it to some other businesses to have payment solutions with our business (like PayPal AAR file) and i don't want they can reflect our class members and they can't have method call (of course in a reflect way) from their apps. Is there any way to protect my code from reflection.
Of course java has security manager but in android we just set null to security manager.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to protect my code from reflection.

Don't publish it.

Or, don't write it in Java (or any other JVM language), but instead write it in C/C++.

Otherwise, no.

Comment: Thank you man. but i need to publish my AAR file. so you advise me to use NDK and native code to protect my critical sections of code?

Comment: @Mohammadmoradyar: I would advise you to not worry about the problem.